# SQL MobileConnect Demographics Table

Tags: mobileconnect

I have added custom attribute X to the MobileConnect Demographics table in Contact Builder.  In Contact Builder, I have linked Table Y to the MobileConnect Demograpics table on attribute X.  I'd like to run a sql activity to create a Data Extension that leverages both tables so I can include personalization in the SMS using columns from table Y.  I'm familiar with data views available at https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_views.htm&type=5 but it doesn't seem like there is an option to query the MobileConnect Demographics table or my specific Attribute X.  Is it possible to query this scenario to create the desired data extension?

Answer (score 6):

Currently there is not a data view which would allow access to attribute X in your example.

In the MC January 2019 release, [two MobileConnect data views](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_january_2019_moc_dataviews.htm&type=5) were made available.

Relating the two objects in MobileConnect Demographics is not necessary and would not allow for personalization from table Y to pull through to an SMS send. You could utilize an [Ampscript LookUp()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookup.htm) function in the SMS send to take attribute X and find the matching value in table Y.